# How to make a news Scroller for our Web Site

Tags: asp.net

I Have a problem that, I want design a Scroller which contains a dynamic data from Database which is updatable by an administrator of the web site and I want to redirect on diffrent Pages when I Selected one of them,and all the values in the scroller is going to upwards from Bottom. I don't know how to implement that?

PLease suggest me for right answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/vertical.html

combined with using Server Side code to generate the data for the scroller.